# Calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek does not work

Tags: java

I want to get the week of the month for a specified date. For example for today(Sunday Sep 14 2014), the result should be 2. For tomorrow(Monday Sep 15 2014), result should be 3.

So i do this :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.setTime(myDate); // myDate is a Date object with the specified date
cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

But this gives me the result 3 for today and tomorrow. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you get the value `myDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me, I get the output of

```
2
3
```

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    Date myDate = new Date(); // today
    System.out.println(dayOfWeek(myDate));
    myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("15.09.2014"); // tomorrow
    System.out.println(dayOfWeek(myDate));
}

private static int dayOfWeek(Date myDate) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    cal.setTime(myDate);
    return cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
}
```

This means that there is a problem with your `myDate` object; try initialising it in the way that I did.

Comment: you are right. Seemed to be a timezone problem with `myDate`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 cal.getFirstDayOfWeek();
```

as in this example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_setfirstdayofweek.htm